# Can DRS be used to challenge which batsman was run out?

Tags: rules, cricket, video-review

This could be a "hilarious" use of the Decision Review System, but nonetheless I want to know if it is possible.

Suppose both the batsmen run to the same end (mix-up, as commentators like to call it), and the fielding side puts down the wicket at one end. The on-field umpire declares one of the batsmen out. Can this batsman invoke DRS to challenge the umpire's decision, in effect, claiming that his partner should be out instead?

A non-hilarious scenario would be if a top-order batsman and a tailender gets involved in the mix-up, and the tailender is given out. The fielding captain might want to invoke the DRS to try to get the more skilled batsman out instead.

Comment: I've seen them go upstairs for this, you think that if it's close they'd do this

Comment: You are right, but that's different from using DRS. On-field umpires can seek help from the TV umpire when they please (subject to some restrictions), but I am not sure if players too can use DRS for that purpose.

Comment: A little off topic, but I remember a match where they spent a good 5 minutes working out which person was out after a major mix up. I think they were both at the same end.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umpire_Decision_Review_System#System):

> A fielding team may use the system to dispute a "not out" call ...

and

> At their discretion, field umpires may request the Third Umpire ... to determine run outs ...

These in combination would seem to suggest that the fielders can appeal the 'not-out' decision of the second batsman. The field umpires would then defer to the video umpire for a decision.
Note that because UDRS requires clear contradiction to the original call, the video would have to definitively show the 'not-out' batsman being nearest to the crease. Any hint of the distances being indeterminate would result in upholding the decision and a loss of review for the fielding team.

Answer (score -1):

On close runout calls On-filed umpires takes help from TV umpire, then there is no point of asking  DRS (because the same answer will come even if he asks for DRS). Even in the confusing situation (both batsman are at the same end) can be handled by taking help of TV umpire.

Comment: You are right, however, a lot of players have been very lousy with the use of DRS, often challenging blatantly obvious decisions only to look foolish on the big screen. Even if the on-field umpire doesn't refer to the TV umpire (because he thinks the decision is obvious enough), do the laws permit the players to challenge it?